# Looking for a modestly priced Wireless Keyboard & Mouse Combo

Tags: wireless, keyboards, mice

I am looking into buying a new mouse and keyboard combo. I define "combo" as in using one single USB port for both devices.

I strongly prefer to buy on Amazon, but I can live without.

Preferred Price range is $60 - $125 USD (~ £40 - £90), but I can be flexible.

### Shared Requirements:

- Wireless
- Excellent battery performance (Ideally 18+ months)
- No Bluetooth, unless the devices include a Bluetooth USB transmitter
- Full/Regular Size (No "mini" or "travel" sizes)
- Right-Handed
- QWERTY
- Not the Anker model `98ANWPSS-K1M1A` (but can be similar)

### Keyboard Requirements:

- Full key set, which include dedicated<sup>1</sup> numpad and function keys
- Minimal+ media keys (such as Play, Pause, Stop, RW, FF) and volume control
- [Windows Key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sG0IB.jpg)
- Quiet

#### Keyboard Like to Haves:

- OS Sleep key is nice
- Shortcut to calculator is also nice
- Flat Keys
- Wrist bar
- I am a programmer, so a dedicated<sup>1</sup> Pause (Break) button is nice
- I take screen shots, so a dedicated<sup>1</sup> Print Screen button is also nice

### Mouse Requirements/Preferences:

- 5-button design
- Mouse wheel includes the "left/right" clicks
- Rubber thumb (preferred)
- Laser preferred over optical, but not required
- I use a mouse pad, so doesn't need any special tracking requirements

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Without the use of a special function key.</sub>

Comment: Logitech has a great unifying software (so you can obtain them separately)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to go with the [Logitech<sup>®</sup> Wireless Wave Combo MK550](http://support.logitech.com/en_us/product/wireless-wave-combo-mk550).

[Amazon list price](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003VAHYNC): **$54.00** [image: Passed]

[image] 
<sup>Image from [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com)</sup>

---

Here's how it compared to my requirements:

### Shared Requirements:

- Wireless [image: Passed]
- Excellent battery performance (Ideally 18+ months) [image: Passed]
- No Bluetooth, unless the devices include a Bluetooth USB transmitter [image: Passed]
- Full/Regular Size (No "mini" or "travel" sizes) [image: Passed]
- Right-Handed [image: Passed]
- QWERTY [image: Passed]
- Not the Anker model `98ANWPSS-K1M1A` (but can be similar) [image: Passed]

### Keyboard Requirements:

- Full key set, which include dedicated<sup>1</sup> numpad and function keys [image: Passed]
- Minimal+ media keys (such as Play, Pause, Stop, RW, FF) and volume control [image: Passed]
- Windows Key [image: Passed]
- Quiet [image: Disputed]

#### Keyboard Like to Haves:

- OS Sleep key is nice [image: Passed]
- Shortcut to calculator is also nice [image: Passed]
- Flat Keys [image: Failed]
- Wrist bar [image: Passed]
- I am a programmer, so a dedicated<sup>1</sup> Pause (Break) button is nice [image: Passed]
- I take screen shots, so a dedicated<sup>1</sup> Print Screen button is also nice [image: Passed]

### Mouse Requirements/Preferences:

- 5-button design [image: Passed]
- Mouse wheel includes the "left/right" clicks [image: Passed]
- Rubber thumb (preferred) [image: Passed]
- Laser preferred over optical, but not required [image: Passed]
- I use a mouse pad, so doesn't need any special tracking requirements [image: Passed]